# Altering page / category names in breadcumbs

Tags: functions

Can anyone assist me in getting my breadcrumbs to show a different word?

At the moment the breadcrumbs are showing the title rather than the page name. However even the page name is not ideal as it is lowercase.

So ideally I would like to set up a function to when a page is displayed in the breadcrumb replace that with the word 'Xxxxxx'

Thanks!

Comment: Give me a link so I can see the problem and I can let you know how to solve it.

Comment: https://www.planninggeek.co.uk/planning/gpdo/dwellinghouse/satellite-dishes/ is an example. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that displays breadcrumbs?

Comment: Using Yoast - not sure of their code

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to your CSS.

```
.breadcrumb_last {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, I used `text-transform: capitalize;`, to make the text looks like you need.

In case you don't know how to add CSS, [check this out](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).

Comment: Thanks - but currently it is using the page title (wordy) rather than the page name (short)

So "GPDO" instead of "General Permitted Development Order (GPDO)"
"Dwelling House" instead of "Permitted development rights of a house"

Which may or maynot be the same as the page name.

But even the page name would be better than the page title